# Missing (operator) in query expression

Tags: c#, ms-access

Lid is an autonumber field in ms access.
Error Message: Missing (operator) in query expression 'Lid='

```
db.Search_Grid_Add(LoanInfo_dgv, "Select * From Loan_Info Where Lid=" + LoanId_cb.Text + "");
```

Comment: [update]
The search is working fine but this error comes when i close the form.

Comment: Are you sure LoanId_cb.Text is not null or empty?

Comment: Can u post the method where it is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `LoanId_cb.Text` is don't parsed as int?
Try:

```
int lid;
string lidText = LoanId_cb.Text.Trim();
if(int.TryParse(lidText , out lid))
{
    db.Search_Grid_Add(LoanInfo_dgv, "Select * From Loan_Info Where Lid="+lidText );
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show(lidText + " can't be parsed as int.");
}
```

Comment: What is the difference? except _+ ""_?

Comment: adding a message box says can't be parsed as int but it works without else condition no error is coming

Comment: @alternatefaraz If message box appears that indicates the text in your combo box can't be parsed as integer, then your query can't works correct.